# Group count results by date between two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, union

I have 2 different tables, users and votes. I would like to get a query to count total users and total votes (not sum) by date.
**users**

```
id | created_at
```

**votes**

```
id | created_at
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
date       | total users | total votes
2012-06-01 | 50          | 90
2012-06-01 | 23          | 0*
2012-06-01 | 80          | 12
```

*It should take into account that on some days no votes were made

I know how to make the 2 separate queries

```
SELECT DATE(created_at), count(id)
FROM vote
GROUP by DATE(created_at)
ORDER by DATE(created_at) DESC
```

but I don't know how to join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DATE(created_at),
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Votes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalVotes',
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Users' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalUsers'
FROM
(
    SELECT created_at, 'Votes' `Type` FROM vote
    UNION ALL
    SELECT created_at, 'Users'        FROM Users
) t
GROUP by DATE(created_at)
ORDER by DATE(created_at) DESC
```

Comment: can you help me on this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063572/mysql-row-count-by-date-in-between

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(created_at),SUM(usercolumnname) as totalusers,
SUM(//votescolumnname) as totalvotes from users u,votes v
where u.date=v.date
GROUP BY u.DATE(created_at)
ORDER BY u.DATE(created_at) DESC
```

Comment: It'd be nice to have some explanatory text with this answer, rather than just a block of code.

Comment: @Hbcdev - Why to only this answer? Other answers are also just a block of code.

Comment: This was the answer I read first. But yeah, I agree that all the others could use some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT created_at, SUM(votes) AS 'TotalVotes', SUM(users) AS 'TotalUsers'
FROM(SELECT DATE(created_at) created_at, COUNT(ID) votes, 0 users 
      FROM votes GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
     UNION 
     SELECT DATE(created_at) created_at, 0 votes, COUNT(ID) users 
     FROM Users GROUP BY DATE(created_at)) t
GROUP BY created_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: You need to use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`.