# mysql: Row count by date in between

Tags: mysql

[image]

From the screenshot shown, it is failed/missing to show the count of date 
'2018-06-23' ,2018-06-25,2018-06-26,2018-06-27 , can you help me to write the correct query so that i get count of missing dates. I am trying to get count of total number of  rows on particular date(created_date).

```
SELECT count(book_id) as count,created_date as cdate
FROM `bookdetails`
WHERE  (created_date >= '2018-06-21' AND created_date <='2018-06-27')
GROUP by DATE(created_date)
ORDER BY MIN(created_date)
```

Expected output:

```
count   |     cdate
----------------------
98           2018-06-21
39           2018-06-22
0            2018-06-23  //because no data
39           2018-06-24
XX           2018-06-25
XX           2018-06-26
XX           2018-06-27
```

Table: `bookdetails` structure
[image]

Comment: can you share your database data ...! and also try with `ORDER BY created_date`

Comment: share your dataset and expected answer dataset

Comment: @Dr.Strange if i use `ORDER BY created_date` then i am getting dublicate ORDER BY created_date  http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20180627-bmj3-92kb.jpg

Comment: your query work properly in your data some mismatch ...!

Comment: i updated with my question with expected output

Comment: there is any `book id` there you want date...?

Comment: @Dr.Strange here is structure http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20180627-vwfu-227kb.jpg

Comment: @AshutoshSingh can you please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date generation and join need to show date that doest exist

```
 select count(book_id) as count,date(C_date) as cdate from

        (
        select * from 
        (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) C_date from
         (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
         (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
         (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
         (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
         (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
        where C_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
        ) All_date

        left join bookdetails
        on date(created_date)=All_date.C_date

        where ( date(All_date.C_date) >= '2018-06-21' AND date(All_date.C_date) <='2018-06-27')

        group by date(C_date)
        order by  date(C_date) asc
```

Comment: @Ashutosh do you have any data for 23rd date?

Comment: No there is no data for 23rd.  YOur query gives error ` MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'created_date' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @AshutoshSingh check now i have edited hope it will work and checked in my end

Comment: @AshutoshSingh check now ,i have edited hope it will work and i checked my in my end it shows correct result

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply use `BETWEEN` instead of `=> and <=`.

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM bookdetails 
 WHERE created_date BETWEEN lowerdate AND upperdate
```

Show us your backend. We'll be able to assist you better.
And what is the expected result?

Comment: Great, but I also need to see your data. It also seems like 2018-06-24 is displaying a different count result than what you expect.

Comment: how to share data in stackoverflow. this table has 1100 data and have foreign key mapping